# Is the following set polyhedral at all of its points?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra

I'm trying to understand the following definition:

> Let $x \in A \subset \mathbb R^n$. We say that $A$ is *polyhedral* at $x$ iff there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a polyhedron $B$ such that $A \cap U = A \cap B$.

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1, \ x_i \geq 0\}$.

> Is $A$ polyhedral at each of its points?

Intuitively, it seems to me like the answer should be yes: $A$ is a convex polytope, which is just a special kind of polyhedron, and polyhedra should be polyhedral at each of their points (right?). I'm not really sure how to formally prove this from the definition though.

Comment: How is polihedron defined there?

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez "A set obtained as the intersection of a finite family of closed half-spaces of $\mathbb R^n$; accordingly polyhedra are closed convex sets, not always bounded."

Comment: I suppose you meant $A\cap U=B\cap U$

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez No, that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited (seems the in the equality of the question was actually $A\cap U=A\cap B$, although that seems strange to me).

Your set $A$ is a polyhedron, because it is the intersection of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq 1$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq 1$, and $x_i\geq0$.

Thus, for every point $x$ of $A$ and nhood $U$ of $x$, you can pick $U=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B=A$ and you have $A\cap U=B\cap A$, that is, $A$ is polyhedral at $x$.